# Colores en la forma feminina o masculina

Tags: gramática, género, colores

Vi una oración en un libro *El arte de no amargarse la vida* (España):

> El resto fue a parar al mantel, que quedó teñido por una espesa mancha **rojo oscuro**.

Si "*rojo oscuro*" se refiere a "*una espesa mancha*", ¿por qué no se escribó "*roja oscura*"?

En realidad, en un fuente leí que algunos colores pueden ser solo en la forma masculina. Aun así, no sé de que depende esto. ¿Pueden ser unas diferencias entre dialectos en Hispanoamérica y España?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Por si en la oración "El resto fue a parar al mantel, que quedó teñido por una espesa mancha rojo oscuro." las palabras "rojo oscuro" se refieren al "mantel"...en este caso sí que esta cadena las respuestas son suficientes. En relación con esto, una pregunta - ¿a qué se refiere "rojo oscuro" en esta oración?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I do not think that answers the question. "Rojo" is a color that usually changes in the feminine form ("una mancha roja"). It is not one of those "invariant colors" listed in that other question. Something different is happening here...

Comment: @wimi Ahora supongo que "rojo oscuro" se refiere al "mantel". En inglés en Google Translate se traduce como "The rest went to the tablecloth, which was stained by a thick dark red stain.". Pero en realidad creo que esto significa "The rest went to the tablecloth, which due to being stained became dark red coloured."

Comment: Considero que wimi ha dado con la clave en su respuesta, pero me gustaría destacarte un trozo de la cita: "se supone, en estos casos, la elisión del sustantivo masculino color", es decir, se supone que la frase sería "... quedó teñido por una espesa mancha (de) color rojo oscuro", de ahí que se escriba en masculino. No creo que exista diferencia dialectal entre España e Hispanoamérica al respecto. Tu primera traducción al inglés me parece correcta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Del [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/colores) (negritas mías):

> Cuando funcionan como adjetivos, si son de dos terminaciones (*blanco, -ca; negro, -gra; rojo, -ja; amarillo, -lla*, etc.), se usa la forma masculina o la femenina según sea el género del sustantivo al que modifican: *falda roja, pantalón negro*. **Pero si, para designar matices, el nombre de color se halla a su vez modificado por otro, o por un adjetivo como claro, oscuro o similares, lo normal, de acuerdo con el uso mayoritario, es usar ambos términos en masculino, incluso en referencia a un sustantivo femenino**: «*Leichtlinii, de gran flor rojo oscuro*» (Alonso *Plantas* [Esp. 1980]); se supone, en estos casos, la elisión del sustantivo masculino *color*; **no obstante, también es posible la concordancia en femenino:** «*La tierra era marrón clara*» (Bolaño *Detectives* [Chile 1998] 369).

Es decir, los colores como *rojo* deben normalmente concordar con sustantivos femeninos (*una mancha roja*). Pero si el color está modificado por un adjetivo como "oscuro" o "claro", lo más común es escribir el color y el adjetivo en masculino (*una mancha rojo oscuro*), aunque también es posible hacerlos concordar con el sustantivo (*una mancha roja oscura*).

En la frase

> El resto fue a parar al mantel, que quedó teñido por una espesa mancha rojo oscuro.

el color *rojo oscuro* se refiere de hecho a la mancha, no al mantel.